# Get current year first month and first day in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a SP and I want to get the current year and the first day and first month of the year.

For example, for this year : `2014-01-01;`
For `2015 : 2015-01-01;`

I tried

```
@data datetime , @test datetime

SELECT @test = GETDATE()
set @test = CAST( YEAR(@test)+'-'+'01'+'-'+'01' as char(100))
set @data = CAST( @test as datetime)
```

But it returns 2016 not 2014 any help?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that your are adding day and month to a numeric value. year() returns an integer.

Implicit casting '-' as an int returns 0.

So your expression would result in 2014+0+1+0+1 because when you have one integer and attempting to add (var)chars, sqlserver will attempt to convert everything else to integers.

The best way to manipulate the date to the first day of the year probably is this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: Thumbs up..!! This is a good way to handle it instead of concatenating `01-01` to the date

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to get the result you want:

```
DECLARE @test       DATETIME

SET @test = CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-01-01'

SELECT @test
```

The conversion to `DATETIME` is made automatically when you set the value.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can just modify your snipped a little bit:

```
declare @data datetime , @test datetime

SELECT @test = GETDATE()
set @test = convert(nvarchar(4),YEAR(@test)) +'-'+'01'+'-'+'01'
set @data = @test
```

this will work for you